# getting the position of an Item using indexOf method

Tags: java, object, methods, arraylist, java.util.scanner

The method getPosition return the position of an item in the list using the method indexOf in the class ArrayLinearList, whenever I pass an argument of a String it just returns -1 all the time even if the item is existed in the list

```
  private ArrayLinearList array;
        private Scanner scanner;
        public ArrayShoppingList1()
        {
            array = new ArrayLinearList();
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
        }


    public int getPosition()
        {

        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the Item");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        int z = array.indexOf(name);
        return z;

    }






/** @return index of first occurrence of theElement,
     * return -1 if theElement not in list */
   public int indexOf(Object theElement)
   {
      // search element[] for theElement
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         if (element[i].equals(theElement))
            return i;

      // theElement not found
      return -1;
   }
```

Comment: check theElement parameter using instanceof.

Comment: Can we see what element[] is?

Comment: recommend adding `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(element));` at the beginning of `indexOf()` to double check whats in the array

Answer (score 0):

You may be forgetting to store the string into `array`.

```
array.add("some string here");
```

Or, are you sure the element are you searching for is in the array?

Try using `compareTo()` method instead of `equals` to compare strings.

Comment: I have already another method which add the string to the array if you want i could provide you with the method

Answer (score 0):

Please provide with the whole code. What is `element`?

By the way, try printing out the value of `name` -- what if the first line you read is empty?

Answer (score 0):

In your `indexOf` function:

```
public int indexOf(Object theElement)
   {
      // search element[] for theElement
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         if (element[i].equals(theElement))
            return i;

      // theElement not found
      return -1;
   }
```

The size is likely to be `< 1`. `; another case would be you are having`upper case`and`lower case`letter problem. Try comparing with`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)` function

Comment: That's assuming it's correct to use `element.length`.  It might not be, if `element` is preallocated and not all of the array elements are used, so that 0 <= `size` < `element.length`.  Unfortunately we have no idea what `size` is or how it's set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `theElement` was supplied with a String.

```
public int indexOf(Object theElement)
   {
      String S = (String) theElement;
      // search element[] for theElement
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         if (element[i].equalsIgnoreCase(S))
            return i;

      // theElement not found
      return -1;
   }
```